# javascript .apply.call() and .apply difference

Tags: javascript, apply, call

```
console.log(Function.prototype.apply.call(Math.floor, undefined, [1.75]));
```

is giving one but

```
console.log(Function.prototype.apply(Math.floor, undefined, [1.75]));
```

returning undefined
what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do the second one (the not-working one) first.

Normally, `.apply()` is used as

```
someFunction.apply(thisValue, argsArray)
```

That has an effect like if `thisValue` were some random object and you had

```
thisValue.someFunction = someFunction;
thisValue.someFunction(... argsArray)
```

The function is called with the value of `this` being whatever the first argument is, and the list of arguments being the contents of the array. Inside the `.apply()` function itself, the `this` value is a reference to the function to be called.

Thus, in

```
Function.prototype.apply(Math.floor, undefined, [1.75])
```

we have the `.apply()` function being called such that its own `this` value is `Function.prototype`, which is a function that always returns `undefined`. Thus, that function is called with `Math.floor` (a function) as the value of `this`, and no arguments, because the third argument is ignored. The `Function.prototype` function returns `undefined` because that's what it always does.

OK, so now for the first example:

```
Function.prototype.apply.call(Math.floor, undefined, [1.75])
```

Here we have code involving both `.apply()` and `.call()`.  What will be called in sequence are:

```
Function.prototype.call
Function.prototype.apply
Math.floor
```

The `.call()` function is the start of the chain. It's called, and internally its `this` value will be the `.apply()` function. So what that means is that we want to call `apply` with the list of arguments (and a `this` value) taken from the arguments to `.call()`. In this case, that means `.apply()` will be called so that its internal `this` value will be `Math.floor`, which makes sense because that means the real function we ultimately want to invoke is `Math.floor()`.  Then, the argument list to `.call()` passes `undefined` as the first argument to `.apply()`, meaning that the value of `this` when `Math.floor()` is called will be `undefined`.  Finally the third argument to `.call()` is the array with 1.75 in it, which means that `Math.floor()` will be invoked with one argument, that being 1.75, and it dutifully returns 1.

Answer (score 2):

[`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is just the implementation of the `apply` method that all functions inherit. Calling it will returned `undefined` because there is no actual function to modify. Instead, it should be used like: `Math.floor.apply(undefined, [1.75])`.

`Function.prototype.apply.call` on the other hand is just a way to use the `apply` method without having to worry about it being overriden for the specific function.

Comment: const a = function() {
    this.t = "t"
}
a.prototype.test = function() {console.log("hello")}
a.prototype.test()
then why this is working just fine?

Comment: @Amirreza That code is not working for me.

Comment: const a = function() {
    this.t = "t"
};
a.prototype.test = function() {console.log("hello")};
a.prototype.test();
try this.

Comment: @Amirreza what are you trying to say?